# Passing the SCSS variable to the Svelte component

Tags: javascript, css, sass, svelte

I need to create a button component that can have different colours. I would like, when using the component, to be able to specify as prop a colour e.g. "#ff0000", but also my SCSS variable e.g. "$primary". However, I know that it is not possible to do something like this because SCSS variables are processed at application build stage and not at runtime.

I am currently using this solution. It allows to set the colour of `$primary` when `primary` is passed as prop. However, this only works for one variable - it is not possible to do something like this for both `$primary` and `$secondary`.

```
<script>
    export let fill;

    $: formattedFill = fill === 'primary' ? '' : fill;
</script>

<button style="--fill: {formattedFill}"><slot/></button>

<style lang="scss">
    button{
        background-color: var(--fill, $primary)
    }
</style>
```

Of course, I can create an object e.g.

```
const colors = {
        primary: "#00ff00",
        secondary: "#0000ff"
    }
```

and then refer to it with the value passed in the props. However, for me this solution is silly - I want centralised colour variables, not scattered in several files.